# ArgumentError after upgrading Ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, argument-error

I upgraded to Ruby 2.4 and started getting this error:

ArgumentError in ConfessionsController#index

key must be 32 bytes

```
  # cipher = new_cipher
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = @secret
       # Rely on OpenSSL for the initialization vector
       iv = cipher.random_iv
```

I read the whole internet about it, and people posted about changing the encryption keys. But I don't even have such a files, so I have no idea what to change and how to fix this. 
Could someone please help?

*as response to a comment: I have no idea what @secret is. This is an extraction file and I have no idea how to edit cypher locally or at all. It's not code that I wrote.

Comment: What is `@secret`? How is it generated? How does it compare to using, for example, https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-random_key? Can you successfully generate a 32 byte key using https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Random.html#method-c-random_bytes instead?

Comment: Also, please don't post images of errors. Just copy and paste the text in. [There are many reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008).

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You couldn't possibly search the entire internet, so tell us where you searched, what you tried to solve it. Currently it looks like you didn't try and want us to write a tutorial describing how to debug and program in Ruby, which is off-topic.

Comment: @theTinMan wow this sounded like an extremely passive aggressive response, but thank you for the links. I am new to the community and coding overall, so I didn't know about those guidelines. Thanks for the "welcome." And FYI, I did A LOT of research, and thought it might make more sense to keep the post as short as possible in order to save people time. I did end up figuring it out, just so you know - I was definitely not waiting for anyone to write a tutorial, especially you.

Comment: @anaspaghetti Don't take it personally. Take it as constructive feedback. SO is an amazing resource but only if you use it properly. Tin Man's comment will take you very far on this site -- for example, "keep the post as short as possible" is not the right approach; including all the relevant information from "How to Ask" IS the right approach.

Comment: @anothermh yes, I agree, I am learning! thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: _I have no idea what @secret is_ -- well neither do I, but it's defined somewhere. At some point somewhere in your code there is some line that says `@secret = ...`. That's what I was asking.

Comment: @anothermh yeah, so secret = ... was not part of any of the code I wrote. None of the error was anything I had written, which was the main problem since I didn't have any files to edit. Here is a thread (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25192) where people solve the issue, but I never understood what files they were editing (since I didn't have them)m hence why I asked a question here. Eventually, I solved the issue by upgrading rails 5.0.0 to 5.0.1 which fixed it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the code sample posted in your question is part of a third-party library? You really need to include that information in your question. When you say "I didn't write this" most people will understand it as "someone else at my company wrote this," not "this is part of Rails and was written by someone on the Rails team." Name the library, include a full stack trace, link to the repo, etc. [The checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) is a good place to start.